# Magento 2 on C9. PHP memory_limit problem

Tags: magento2, php, php-7

I installed **Magento 2** on C9.

I installed **PHP 7**, with all necessary extensions (curl, mbstring, mcrypt and etc).

I set the php memory_limit 4096M.
https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/905628/sxvelb6o5xrt3q0tilem

But when I try to enable any extension
I receive this error.
https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/905618/itnd4qy7g7caitzgrrmv

Comment: Did you restart the web server after changing PHP memory limit?

Comment: Hi. 
Thank you for your response.
Sure I restarted the server

Comment: Which version of PHP and Magento are you using

Comment: Magento ver. 2.1.6
PHP Version 7.0.18-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

Answer (score 0):

Increase the PHP memory limit to at least **768MB** for normal operation or **2GB** for testing.

I found in the documentation:

```
Set the PHP memory limit.
Our detailed recommendations are: 
Compiling code or deploying static assets, 756M 
Installing and updating Magento components from Magento Marketplace, 2G Testing
```

Comment: I tested it before and unfortunately nothing worked. I increased memory limit to 1G, 2G and 4G, but I always get this error.
"Your current PHP memory limit is 64M. Magento 2 requires it to be set to 756M or more."

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add -d memory_limit=6G with the command.

```
Php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magrnto setup:static-content:deploy
```